# Fonts and Colors - #region

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to change the font color of the #region and #endregion ?
I dont find this element at `extras/options/fonts and colors`.

Comment: NiMa, why did you change the caption ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in here:

```
TOOLS -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors
```

when you select Text Editor (Under "Show settings for") the Display Item is called `Preprocessor Keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have only recently started using VS2013 but I know that if you link it with your Windows account, you have a "profile" where you can change themes and whatnot. Maybe poke around in there? It should all be housed within VS itself.

Comment: well. I use the dark theme, but I only want to change the #region text/font color. thx anyways

Comment: @lsmoh no problem. sorry I couldnt be of more help!

Comment: DeeWBee: no problem :)