# How to display #region statements in gray or green fonts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to display the #region statements in gray or green fonts in Visual Studio 2013?

Edit: I just want the text after the #region and #endregion to be in a weaker font, because they are used around almost all functional code (not my choice, can't do anything about it.) It interferes with functional code.

Example

#region Some text
functional code
#endregion Some text

They are used heavily in our company and interfere with functional code. It would be nice to display them in a weaker color such as the comments.

Comment: Not an answer but if you use `#region` you're most probably violating *Single responsible principle* and your classes are doing too many things. Don't do that. If you follow SRP then you don't need regions at all.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel maybe not... i often group heavy comment with regions in case it has to be there, not that i comment that heavy for it reduces readablility, but at least it can be reduced to a single line

Comment: I wouldnt agree @SriramSakthivel, what if i want to hide the private variables within a region? It would be much more readable with a region.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 - Fonts and Colors - #region](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392372/visual-studio-2013-fonts-and-colors-region)

Comment: `#region` is just for IDE. so I think it does not violate such rules.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger You should try not to comment also. Express your comments in code. Your code say what it does not the comments.  http://apdevblog.com/comments-in-code/

Comment: @CarbineCoder Why do you have many private variables? If you have many things not cohesive, then you're clearly violating SRP.

Comment: Forget about many variables, if there are more than two variables i can hide them away with a collapsed region. Why would i want things to clutter my screen which can be hidden?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel as I said I am not doing heavy commenting on a regular basis... reduces readablility ... I just wanted to point at a use for #regions

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - A good use I've had to use regions for in the past is to make sure that an external company I had to work with didn't modify a section of code at all... a big warning region worked pretty well. I do agree with your points however and normally a descriptive method/variable name is enough to warrant lack of comments

Comment: @CarbineCoder There is no reason to collapse just two or three variables with a #region. It will look even better without region.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel _han shot first_ I didnt do it . Jokes apart it got me thinking why were you saying this. And lo this came up - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/53114/101271. Thanks anyways, this is new to me :) P.S. I do follow SRP but still use regions to collapse stuff and keep it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a free extension that solved all of my region problems, including the one above:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca

Answer (score 5):

In Options, change highlighted *collapsed-* things as you want.

**More Description Appended Below for who may not see image**

- in VisualStudio, Tools>Options, and go to **Fonts and Colors**.
  There are three items can change; Collapsed Text (Collapsed), Collapsed Text (Expanded), Collapsible Region.

[image]

Comment: You might want to add some text to explain how to get to this option incase the image becomes unavailable

Comment: @Sayse // got it. description added.

Comment: Changing `Collapsed Text` will also affect comment blocks. Not sure if OP wanted this.